# NPN inverter alternative that takes up less space on the board

Tags: transistors, inverter, npn

Here I have an NPN inverter circuit which consist of 2 separate NPN transistors and 3 resistors. It does the job, but it takes too much space on the board. Is there any alternative to this circuit that take less space? Can I use something like this https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/vt6x12-1535580.pdf ? Is this the best alternative I can find or there's a better option?

[image: NPN inverter]

Use case:
This circuit is controlled by MCU through the base pin. The logic level voltage of the MCU is 3.3V. The use case here is it to trigger pairing mode on the BT chip using it's supply (1.8V) as the logic level on the BT module should not exceed 1.8V

Comment: "Here I have an NPN inverter circuit". No you don't. That's two inverters which make a non-inverting buffer as explained in my answer to [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1072809?noredirect=1).

Comment: It would also be nice to have more context about how and where the circuit is to be used. What does it drive? What is driving it? Etc.

Comment: @jonk this is controlled by MCU through the base pin. The logic level voltage of the MCU is 3.3V. The use case here is it to trigger pairing mode on the BT chip using it's supply (1.8V) as the logic level on the BT module should not exceed 1.8V

Comment: @user1258202 So what you actually want is a **logic level converter** on a small footprint.

Comment: @HarrySvensson not really, as regular logic level converter inverts the logic level voltage and this not the result I expect. When the input is LOW the output also should be LOW, not HIGH :)

Comment: @user1258202 Let me translate what you just said in very simple terms, "It is not *A*, I want *A*". Your understanding of what a "regular logic level converter" appears to be wrong.

Comment: @user1258202 When using an MCU, unless you are using a constrained peripheral and not software to change the I/O pin state, it should not matter at all whether you use "0" or "1" to activate the purpose. So forcing the situation is just being "difficult," I think. I don't know anything about BT chips, though, and I don't feel a full understanding of what you need there. So I'll leave this to others who do.

Comment: @jonk it takes time for MCU to initialise and invert the logic, so as a result the IO of BT could be triggered and this causes unexpected behaviour of the BT chip during it's initialisation. I already tried to invert the logic in the software, but as I said it causes me problems...

Comment: @user1258202 During power-up, most MCU's have their I/O as "high impedance inputs." This means you can either use a pull-down or else a pull-up resistor externally to set the default, power-up value of the I/O pin prior to setting it to an output. Is there a reason you can't take that approach? (No matter what you do, if the MCU sets the I/O to an input on POR, you have no control until your software gets time to change it to an output, anyway. So I'm not certain I entirely accept your logic, yet.)

Comment: @jonk Something smells fishy

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to translate a signal from 3.3 or 5V to 1.8V there are better ways. For example, for (up to) 3.6V to 1.8V, single channel, you could use a [74AUP1T34](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AUP1T34.pdf).  About 1mm x 1mm in the smallest package.

Answer (score 1):

You have given no details on the input impedance of the circuit you are trying to drive. If it is reasonably high then you can use a potential divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPjTRz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A potential divider level converter.*

Note that the sum of R1 + R2 is 33k and that R2 is 18k so that 3.3 V is divided down to 1.8 V.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a logic level MOSFET (such as [AO3402](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3402.pdf)) instead of a BJT, it's only 2 components including the pull-up resistor. The output will be logical inverted to the input, a solution to this is to just invert it in software on the microcontroller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPLdDEb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you for some strange reason cannot make the signal inverted in software, then you can just cascade the schematic above.

---

There is no series resistor nor a pull-down resistor on the gate in the schematic above because what you are driving doesn't consume a lot of power nor is the microcontroller strong enough to cause absurd ringing.

Comment: If I would want to invert it in the software I would use a regular NPN transistor, but this not what I expect (please see my provided schematic what I'm trying to achieve here). It takes time for MCU to invert it and as result the IO of the BT module will be triggered and this causes unexpected behaviour of the BT chip during it's initialisation (e.g. won't automatically connects to the paired device)

Comment: @user1258202 You are kidding right? What time does it take to treat an output pin as 1 compared to zero? Nothing.

Comment: This also works with a BJT.

Comment: @JackCreasey It could be that the output has a certain value when the MCU starts, meaning it takes time for the MCU to output the other value (because that can only be done when the reset sequence is done and code is running)

Comment: @immibis And then you need another resistor. OP's problem appeared to be physical size.

Comment: @immibis Most MCUs configure all GPIO pins as inputs after a reset. Of course you have to initialize, but that is part of your design ….and that would be the choice between an invertor or a buffer.